# react-loadable - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

I'm trying to implement lazy-loading components with react-loadable. I've followed their guide but I can't get it to work.

I've got 3 loadable components

```
const LazyOne = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'lazy-1' */"./components/LazyOne"),
  loading: <h1>wait</h1>
});

const LazyTwo = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'lazy-2' */"./components/LazyTwo"),
  loading: <h1>wait</h1>
});

const LazyThree = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'lazy-3' */"./components/LazyThree"),
  loading: <h1>espera</h1>
});
```

At first the webpack build would break because it threw an **unexpected input** error on the import. So I added this to my **.babelrc**

```
"plugins": [
    // all my other plugins...
    "syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
```

Now the build is successfull and if I use **webpack-bundle-analyzer** I see all lazy builds built correctly!

But when I access my page that is rendered like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <LazyOne {...this.props} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}
```

This throws:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I see nothing mentioning this anywhere in react-loadables github or even code-splitting sections in webpack. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've changed things up a bit and noticed it fails to load the lazy chunk.

my url is like this: **localhost:3000/some/rest/1/edit**

and the app is trying to fetch: localhost:3000/some/rest/1/lazy-1.bundle.js

Where should I specify the path?

Comment: In which component you are getting this error?

Comment: @Madhavan.V When I try to render any Lazy Component. In my example I tried to render LazyOne.

Comment: Can you check the console for the error, I have faced this kind of issue when I was trying to display some values in render method.

Comment: @Madhavan.V It's the exact same error I posted in my question: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I also had some issues with this. I would try to remove it from `react-loadable` to ensure the component works. I had an error where it was swallowing errors from the inner component.

Comment: May be you are rendering value which is containing `object`. Like, `address: { city: "city name", location: { lat: "122", lng: "999" } }` and trying to print it like `<label>{address.city} - {address.location}</label>`

Comment: @kwelch they worked fine without loadable. I decided to add it and it broke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I solved all problems about the bundles being loaded by the main app. The error changed!

So I narrowed it down:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

**Means the main bundle is not loading the lazy bundles properly (and most probably failing at loading them). For example in my case the generated lazy bundles: lazy-1, lazy-2 and lazy-3 were being put on the wrong folder by webpack. I just had to fix that**

After this fix there is still another change to be made since the error will change to this with the code I presented:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

But why you might ask? It's simple! The **loading** param does not take JSX but it takes a component type like this:

```
// WRONG! AND WILL THROW ERROR
const LazyOne = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'lazy-1' */"./components/LazyOne"),
  loading: <h1>wait</h1>
});

// RIGHT!
const LoadingComponent = () => (<h1>wait</h1>);

const LazyOne = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'lazy-1' */"./components/LazyOne"),
  loading: LoadingComponent
});
```

And just like that my problems were solved (since my components were not throwing any errors)

Answer (score 0):

Took me hours to figure out but it turns out that just adding 'async' can break all hell out in React.. and you don't get any good feedback why.

```
const renderB2bApp = (store, callback) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <B2BApp store={store} />
    </Provider>,
    appElement,
    callback,
  );
};

const B2BApp = async (props) => { {/* <--- async here!! remove it */ }
    // ...    
    // it doesn't matter if you don't use `await` even just adding the async destroys it
}
```

If you need to do async stuff then you need to render something immediately and then use hooks or state to update the component. So do not add async inside the `ReactDom.render` subcomponent!